# Parallels Plesk Panel unable to connect to database

Tags: database, parallels

I don't know how to create a database into Parallels Plesk Panel, so I tried it going to the PhpMyAdmin creating the database and modifying the admin user password from there, but now the system is showing me the next error:

[image]

```
ERROR: PleskFatalException
Unable to connect to database: saved admin password is incorrect.

0: common_func.php3:150
    psaerror(string 'Unable to connect to database: saved admin password is incorrect.')
1: auth.php3:107
ERROR: PleskFatalException
Unable to connect to database: saved admin password is incorrect.

0: common_func.php3:150
    psaerror(string 'Unable to connect to database: saved admin password is incorrect.')
1: auth.php3:107
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: What I have modified, was the PhpMyAdmin password access, so the solution was to contact my hosting service provider and they solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to connect to psa database:

```
mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` psa
```

In case you cannot connect, try to update admin user for mysql with this password. After that Plesk should be able to connect with this database.

Answer (score 0):

I also add this problem, for me the above solution didnt work.  it appears plesk has been evolving it's password protection (e.g. .psa.shadow is now aes-cbc encrypted)

this kb article worked for me - i'm using plesk 11.09
http://kb.parallels.com/112492

I got myself into this situation when i got a cloud vm instance where i couldnt log into mysql.  so i mysqld_safe and updated the admin password to what it was supposed to be, which meant i could log in but I also broke plesk.  this kb got plesk back on its feet again

One thing I found; after following these steps I am not able to login to the plesk 'admin' user on the command line, even with the password i specified in the env variable !  so before resetting the admin password as per this kb article, create another mysql user with all privileges.  then use the new user so you dont have the problem of sharing a user with plesk

as to why this happens i dont know, i'm interested if someone does.  what appears to be happening is that the ch_admin_passwd of psa starts mysql with security disabled, does some operation on the password (obfuscate?, encrypt?, add salt?)  and sets that password for the admin user.  whatever that interim operation means that while plesk can log into mysql as admin because it's consistent with itself, the cleartext version of the password specified to ch_admin_passwd does not work on the command line with mysql